# Can car traffic be managed by mathematical formula?

Tags: mathematical-modeling, applications, computational-mathematics

How car traffic is managed? Is it managed by mathematical algorithm? Or by human(operator)? If it's by operator, can it be managed mathematically? Or is it by physics? By what theories/formula?

Because someone told me that traffic in US is managed by satellite and it is synchronized each other.

Comment: What do you mean by "managed"? Cars in the US are operated by human drivers who travel on each vehicle and attempt to optimize their own safety and arrival times (according to some individualized trade-off) based on information they gain by looking out the window to see where the other cars are. That doesn't seem to be much of a mathematical question ...

Comment: @HenningMakholm : maybe in some places, the traffic lights can be controlled in order to manage traffic

Comment: Sorry for my bad English, I meant "traffic lights" @HenningMakholm :-)

Comment: What is it that you are asking exactly? Just like for the weather, there are mathematical models that allow us to describe car traffic. One can then use these models and knowledge of the current state of car traffic (obtained e.g. via satellite or traffic cams) to "predict" the traffic flow in the near future, and possibly run some simulations to adaptively manage (i.e. change the state of) stop-lights to try to maximise the traffic flow and minimise congestion. I don't know if anyone bothers doing this, other than researchers in applied mathematics.

Answer (score 3):

One possible way to model car traffic is to use min-plus or max-plus semirings.
See for instance these slides: ￼[Fundamental Traffic Diagrams : A Maxplus Point of View](http://jpquadrat.free.fr/Pise.pdf), where you can find more references at the end.

See also [Bart De Schutter's Traffic and transportation networks publications](http://www.dcsc.tudelft.nl/~bdeschutter/pub/pub_by_topic_traffic.html), with 253 entries.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand (and I may be way off here), traffic lights can be programmed based on the expected amount of traffic flow through that intersection at certain times of day. Researchers can collect data on the amount of traffic on certain roads at certain times, and then use this data to optimize the timing of the lights to avoid congestion.

So, in a sense, there is some math involved with the data collection and optimization problem, although I don't think there is a specific formula or algorithm that gets followed.